# Retrieve multiple rows with query using AND and OR

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.1, relational-division

I want to retrieve multiple rows using same id's. Therefore having this table "component_property", I would like to have as results 2 records, id's: 8 and 9 according to my SQL query (check below), but of course and retrieving nothing since I'm checking if `cp.property_id = 9102` and later and checking if `cp.property_id = 8801` which at the same time is impossible.

```
ID;type_id;name;desc;property_id,value
--------------------------------------
8;3832;"amplifier1";"";8801;"3"
8;3832;"amplifier1";"";9102;"4015"
9;3832;"amplifier2";"";8801;"3"
9;3832;"amplifier2";"";9102;"4016"
```

This is the query I have at this moment which retrieves nothing.

```
SELECT c.id, c.type_id, cp.property_id, cp.value 
FROM components_component AS c 
INNER JOIN components_componentproperty AS cp 
ON c.id = cp.component_id 
WHERE 
(cp.property_id = 9102  AND cp.value IN ('4015', '4016')) 
OR
(cp.property_id = 8801  AND cp.value = '3') 
AND c.type_id = 3832
```

component ===> component_property <=== property

### component

```
id serial NOT NULL,
type_id integer NOT NULL,
name character varying(50) NOT NULL,
description character varying(255),
```

### component_property

```
id serial NOT NULL,
component_id integer NOT NULL,
property_id integer NOT NULL,
value character varying(255),
```

### property

```
id serial NOT NULL,
code character varying(10),
preferred_name character varying(50),
```

My expected result would be:

```
id;name
-------
8;amplifier1
9;amplifier2
```

Comment: show your expected output

Comment: show also structure / sample data extract from `components_component` - i see also that you have `c.type_id = 3832` maybe you meant `cp.type_id  ...`

Comment: @unique_id uhmmm, I get 4 records, I should get just 2 records which represent the 2 components which match with the values of the properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a case of relational division:

```
SELECT c.id, c.name
FROM   components_componentproperty cp1
JOIN   components_componentproperty cp2 USING (component_id)
JOIN   components_component         c   ON c.id = cp1.component_id
WHERE  cp1.property_id = 9102  AND cp1.value IN ('4015', '4016')
AND    cp2.property_id = 8801  AND cp2.value = '3'
AND    c.type_id = 3832
GROUP  BY c.id;
```

We have assembled an arsenal of relevant techniques here:

- [How to filter SQL results in a has-many-through relation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7364969/how-to-filter-sql-results-in-a-has-many-through-relation/7774879#7774879)

#### Check for a large number of properties

You can expand the above query and for a hand full of properties it will be among the fastest possible solutions. For a bigger number it will be more convenient (and also starting to be faster) to go this route:

Example for 5 properties, expand as needed:

```
SELECT c.id, c.name
FROM  (
   SELECT id
   FROM  (
      SELECT component_id AS id, property_id  -- alias id just to shorten syntax
      FROM   components_componentproperty
      WHERE  property_id IN (9102, 8801, 1234, 5678, 9876)  -- expand as needed
      GROUP  BY 1,2
      ) cp1
   GROUP  BY 1
   HAVING count(*) = 5  -- match IN expression
   ) cp2
JOIN   components_component c USING (id);
```

The extra step of the inner subquery `cp1` is only necessary, because you obviously have multiple entries per `(component_id, property_id)` in `components_componentproperty`. We *could* fold `cp1` and `cp2` into one and check

```
HAVING count(DISTINCT property_id) = 5
```

But I expect that to be more expensive, since `count(DISTINCT col)` needs one sort operation *per row*.

For very long lists `IN` is a bad choice. Consider:

- [Optimizing a Postgres query with a large IN](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/91247/3684)

Comment: what about if there are more properties to compare. Properties are dynamic so, I can compare 2,3 or 10.

Comment: @Ruben: I added a solution for that.

Comment: It did the job: SELECT c.id, c.name
FROM components_component AS C
WHERE
c.id IN (SELECT component_id FROM components_componentproperty WHERE property_id = 9102  AND value IN ('4015', '4016'))
AND
c.id IN (SELECT component_id FROM components_componentproperty WHERE property_id = 8801  AND value IN ('3'))

Comment: @Ruben: Yes, should work, too. Test performance with `EXPLAIN ANALYZE`.  Joins are typically faster than `IN`. For many duplicate matches `EXISTS` is typically faster. In short: `IN` is only competitive for small sets.