# Postgresql: the best way to check if column is equal to multiple values simultaneously

Tags: sql, postgresql, relational-division

If I want to check if a column is equal to one or other value, I write:

```
where col1 in (1, 4, 9);
```

But if I want to check if a column is equal to those values simultaneously,
I should write:

```
where col1 = 1 and col1 = 4 and col1 = 9;
```

Is there in SQL any short form for this, like in?

Example:

```
c1  |  c2
----------- 
1   |  1
1   |  2
1   |  3
```

Select c1 from tablename where c2 = 1 and c2 = 2;

In result set I want **1**

Comment: Ehh, a column can (at most) have only one *scalar* value for a row.

Comment: do you want 'or'??
where col1 = 1 OR col1 = 4 OR col1 = 9;

Comment: There are arrays in PostgreSQL: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/arrays.html. But I'm not sure if it is what he is looking for  (and I think it is not). If it is a array column you could do something like this:  WHERE col1[1] = 4 and col1[2] = 9;

Comment: One value for a row - yes, of course. But it may have many values for the entire  column.

Comment: @Pau Chorro, yes, I am aware of arrays and use them, but I think that their usage is rather slow...
no, I have not array column. Example:

c1  |  c2 
1    |  1
1    |  2
1    |  3

Select * from tablename there c2 = 1 and c2 = 2;

Comment: In that case you should rephrase your question (like: "there exist rows for this column for all values in (1,4,9)" ) which comes *very close* to relational division. (but which rows do you want in the resultset?)

Comment: He is editing.... IMO he wants relational division.

Comment: updated the question.

Comment: I'm still trying to understand the question... LOL

Comment: @PauChorro
Select distinct(c1) from tablename where c2 = 1 AND c2 = 2;

Comment: Select distinct on(c1) from tablename col2 in (1, 4, 9) // -> postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-select-distinct . Otherwhise: @Stepan Pavlov  col2 = 1 and col2 = 2 your result will be 0 rows....

Comment: Here are similar questions:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29117449/retrieve-multiple-rows-with-query-using-and-and-or
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7364969/how-to-filter-sql-results-in-a-has-many-through-relation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Relational division:

```
CREATE TABLE ztable
        ( c1 integer not NULL
        , c2 integer not null
        , PRIMARY KEY (c1,c2)
        );
INSERT INTO ztable(c1,c2) values
 (1   ,  1) -- [c1=1] should match
,(1   ,  2)
,(1   ,  3)
,(2   ,  3) -- [c1=2] should NOT match
,(2   ,  4)
        ;

WITH musthave (val) AS (VALUES (1), (2))
SELECT distinct c1
FROM ztable zt
WHERE NOT EXISTS ( -- we DONT WANT the records
        SELECT * FROM musthave mh
        WHERE NOT EXISTS ( -- for which one of the musthaves is missing
                SELECT * FROM ztable nx
                WHERE nx.c1 = zt.c1
                AND nx.c2 = mh.val
                )
        )
        ;
```

-- For smaller problems (limited set of musthave values) you could just do:

```
SELECT distinct c1
FROM ztable zt
WHERE zt.c2 = 1
AND EXISTS (
        SELECT *
        FROM ztable t2
        WHERE t2.c1 = zt.c1
        AND t2.c2 = 2
        );
```

-- and there is yet another method, which counts the matching c2 values:

```
SELECT DISTINCT zt.c1
FROM ztable zt
JOIN    (
        SELECT c1, COUNT(DISTINCT c2) AS cnt
        FROM ztable t2
        WHERE t2.c2 IN (1, 2)
        GROUP BY c1
        ) zzz ON zzz.c1= zt.c1
WHERE zzz.cnt = 2
    ;
```

Answer (score 1):

PostgreSQL has extended the `<operator> ALL` syntay to arrays, so you can use:

```
WHERE col1 = ALL (ARRAY[1, 4, 9])
```

Comment: trying to get it work, but unsuccessfully:
    create table t1
    (
    c1 integer, 
    c2 integer 
    ); 

    insert into t1 (c1, c2) values (1,1), (1, 2), (1, 3); 

    select * from t1
    WHERE c2 = ALL (ARRAY[1, 2]);

Comment: This clause is working opposite way.   If we say select * from t1
WHERE c2 != ALL (array [1, 2]);
it gives c2 = 3, because it compares our condition against every SINGLE value of our table. It can not compare the condition simultaneously against multiple rows.

Comment: What I gave you matches `where col1 = 1 and col1 = 4 and col1 = 9;` as you wrote. The example you gave is something different that I don't understand. Maybe if you explain in more detail what you really want?